# Is Windows 7 better at utilizing multi-core processors than Windows xp?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-core

Is Windows 7 better at utilizing multi-core processors than Windows xp? Better to have some explanation and proofs with the answer(yes or no).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes I would say it is true Windows 7 out performs Windows XP. The proof and explanation all you need is here:

[Windows 7 Multicore Benchmarking](http://www.infoworld.com/d/windows/windows-7-multicore-how-much-faster-325)

However there is one important factor that other than OS are the software applications designed such and ready to utilise the multi cores which is another limiting factor.

This has been made clear here: [Multi Core in Windows 7 Info](http://www.windowsvienna.com/windows-7-takes-more-advantage-of-multi-core-cpus-a24.html)

So Intel has stressed the Software developers to develop such applications. [Development for Multicores](http://www.geekpedia.com/news297_Intel-To-Developers-Prepare-For-Thousands-Of-Cores.html)